# convert affine format of keypoints (shape of keypoints: [N, 6]) to conventional SIFT format (shape of keypoints: [N, 4])

Tags: python, opencv, sift, affinetransform, keypoint

I have a question about convert affine format (shape of keypoints: [N, 6] which is axis 6 is x, y, A11, A12, A21, A22 respectively).

to

conventional SIFT format (shape of keypoints: [N, 4] and 4 is x, y, scale, angle respectively).

any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
semi code that I've found:

```
def derive_scale_ori(aff_mat):
  scale = np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(aff_mat))
  rot_mat = aff_mat/scale
  ori = np.arctan2(rot_mat[1, 1], rot_mat[0, 0])
  return scale, or
```

where aff_mat is: [[A11, A12],
[A21, A22]]

Are return values correct?

Comment: see https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html. But your equivalence is only true for a rigid rotation, i.e. no shear or skew and uniform scaling in x and y.

Comment: @fmw42, I've found a code that does transformation. code added to question. plz check that return true values.